# Android Google Map cleared by PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR

Tags: android, google-maps, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw a rectangle above the google map to crop a portion of the map.

I placed a googleMap and a custom layout with a canvas like this.

```
<FrameLayout>
   <FrameLayout/>//conatiner for SupportMapFragment
   <MyCustomLayout/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Inside MyCustomLayout, the paints are initiated like this.

```
        linedPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linedPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        linedPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
        linedPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10, 10}, 0));

        bgPaint = new Paint();
        bgPaint.setColor(0x70FFFFFF);

        transparentPaint = new Paint();
        transparentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        transparentPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        transparentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

onDraw is as below.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    try {

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), bgPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mClickStartX, mClickStartY, mClickEndX, mClickEndY, transparentPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mClickStartX, mClickStartY, mClickEndX, mClickEndY, linedPaint);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorController.showError(e);
    }
}
```

This will draw a dim white background above the map, and when the user clicks and drags on it, it will draw a transparent rectangle.

But, when the transparentPaint's xfermode is set to **PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR**, it clears the map itself, resulting as a **black rectangle** shown as below.

[image]

When changing the xfermode to OVERLAY, it doesn't change the map to black, but the background of the canvas will not be changed as I expect.

When switching to a Naver Map fragment, it works as I expect it to be. What can I try to make this work? Please help!

Comment: Why do you need transparent fill? Why only dashed outline is not enough?

Comment: Not my intension. My client likes the transparent thing concept.

Comment: I mean - if your box always transparent - you can draw only outline without any fill.